# React Upload File Typescript FormData parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, form-data

I tried to upload a file to my API using React + Typescript, but I can't get the FormData parameters right.

My states defined as this (I use observable here):
[image]

And here is my upload action:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method accepts...

> a `USVString` or `Blob` (including subclasses such as `File`)

Your `PipelineStore` has a nullable [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) in its `file` property. Either add files by index or iterate the list

```ts
//add by index
formData.append("asda", this.file![0]);

// or iterate
for (const f of this.file!) {
  formData.append("asda", f);
}
```